# Center a div vertically?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm building a responsive website, and I have a div (named 'wrapper'), that I want to be in the center of the page at all times. I figured out how to center it horizontally, because I have a set width percentage. How would I center this vertically, if I DONT have a set height percentage?

```
.wrapper{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding: 3%;
}'
```

Comment: Use margins top bottom auto

Comment: Duplicate of [What's the best way of centering a div vertically with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/396145/254830)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this tutorial**
Centering div vertically and horizontally

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: This answer would be better if it summarized the technique described in the article, rather than linking off-site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery plugin: **[TailorFit](https://github.com/rtheunissen/tailorfit)**
and check out the **[demo](http://dev.fhmp.net/tailorfit/demo/)**.

One way you could use it would be like this:

```
$('#your-div').tailorfit();
```

Because your height is auto, that alone should do the trick.

Full disclosure - I'm the author of the plugin.